# Можно ли ? ::before ::arfter

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, можно ли достучатся из js к псевдоэлементам DOMa?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. И событие на них не повесить.

Comment: Есть несколько способов, но самый хардкорный выглядит так `$('head').append("<style>.span::after{ content:'bar' }</style>");`. Также можно заранее создать класс с прицепленым псевдоэлементом со всеми его свойствами и этот класс через js применять потом к элементу. Не так гибко но и не так костыльно.

Comment: @MishaSaidov, это не доступ к псевдоэлементам.

Comment: @Grundy не подаю, как ответ, но это может в итоге помочь решить проблему.

Comment: @MishaSaidov, какую именно?:)

Comment: спасибо ребята) 
да это на собеседовании вопросик подкатил такой)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если прям очень сильно захотеть, то можно узнать какое-либо свойство:

```js
var style = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('foo'), ':before');
console.log(style.content);
```

```css
#foo::before {
  content: 'Hello world';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

До самого элемента не добраться,
**НО**, никто не мешает получить ссылку на таблицу стилей
 и маниплировать ей как пожелается - по сути элемент и создается правилами CSS.

```js
'use strict';

( function () {

    var
            selectorText = '.button::before',
            button = document.getElementById( 'button' ),
            color = [ 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)', 'rgba(73, 255, 59, 0.4)' ],
            colorInd = 0;

    // Поиск селектора
    var styleSheetList = document.styleSheets, selectorStyle;

    [ ].forEach.call( styleSheetList, function ( CSSStyleSheet ) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < CSSStyleSheet.rules.length; ++i ) {
            if ( CSSStyleSheet.rules[i].selectorText === selectorText ) {
                selectorStyle = CSSStyleSheet.rules[i].style;
                return;
            }
        }
    } );

    if ( !selectorStyle ) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Теперь и далее -
    //    можем использовать нашу ссылку, например для изменения фона
    button.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
        selectorStyle.backgroundColor = colorInd ? color[--colorInd] : color[++colorInd];
    } );

} )();
```

```css
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    margin: 4px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #9caab9;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(124, 138, 153), rgb(108, 122, 137));
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(60, 74, 89, 0.6);
    overflow: hidden;
    user-select: none;
}

/* этим элементом будем манипулировать */
.button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    transition-property: left width;
    transition-duration: 200ms;
}

.button:hover::before {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            /* для примера, она здесь не нужна, но как будто таблиц много */
            body {
                margin: 20px;
                font-family: monospace;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="button" id="button">button</div>
        При клике меняем цвет псевдоэлемента
    </body>
</html>
```